# What is the easiest way to setup Log rotation

Tags: logrotate

Recently, I have setup a script that outputs to a single log file... After quite a while this file begins to become too large to manage. I was wondering what the easiest way is to setup log rotations for every few hundred lines located in the original log file?

Comment: @muru ?? Are you marking all my posts as duplicates because every one you marked so far is not even remotely a duplicate?

Comment: stop exaggerating. I haven't marked all your posts as duplicates and those that I have are pretty much duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `logrotate`, execute this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install logrotate
```

Logrotate's configuration can generally be found in 2 places on Ubuntu (from Digital Ocean):

1. `/etc/logrotate.conf`: this file contains some default settings and sets up rotation for a few logs that are not owned by any system packages. It also uses an include statement to pull in configuration from any file in the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory.
2. `/etc/logrotate.d/`: this is where any packages you install that need help with log rotation will place their Logrotate configuration.

On a standard install you should already have files here for basic system tools like `apt`, `dpkg`, `rsyslog` and so on.
By default, `logrotate.conf` will configure weekly log rotations (`weekly`), with log files owned by the root user and the syslog group (`su root syslog`), with four log files being kept (`rotate 4`), and new empty log files being created after the current one is rotated (`create`).

If you want to learn more about how to use this tool, please visit the following link:  [How To Manage Logfiles with Logrotate on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can also read `man logrotate;man logrotate.conf`.

Comment: You can test it by doing a dry run with `sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf --debug`